# how to link two iphone application via a single button

Tags: ios, url-scheme

i have two iphone apps and want to they able to switch via a single button, anyway to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [URL Schemes](http://furbo.org/2008/10/01/redacted/) to open different applications.

Here's Apple's official information [on the topic](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW26), from [squelart](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW26) in the comments.

Comment: Correct answer. :-)
But linked page looks confusing to me and doesn't give much actual help. Apple's docs: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW26

Comment: Here is the new documentation link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some kind of internet service to bounce any non-textual data between two applications.  If your data can be represented simply within a URI, you can link between two iphone applications by passing that with URL Schemes as Alan Storm suggested.